# React: How to render a text/html http response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, httpresponse

I am creating an app that uploads an .xls file to a server, and the response is a text/html response. I would like to preview the response (exactly as in the developer tool).
Something like:

```
        axios.post(config.serverUrl + "/file", formData)
            .then(response => {

                //Preview response code
            }
```

I tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: {response.data} }}` but that did not work.

Response example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>table, td{    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 9px;
}</style><title>file3500064108648651012.tmp</title></head><body><table>
<tr><td>Sheet 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test1</td><td>test2</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

The preview should then look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>table, td{    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 9px;
}</style><title>file3500064108648651012.tmp</title></head><body><table>
<tr><td>Sheet 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test1</td><td>test2</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example of the response, and also your desired behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to set HTML directly:

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={response} />
```